# Async modifier in C#

Tags: c#

I have the question, what is the difference between these two methods?

```
    async private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
```

Both of them block my UI. I know that I must start another thread to avoid blocking, but I have found:

"An async method provides a convenient way to do potentially long-running work without blocking the caller's thread".

I'm a bit confused.

Comment: you can use async but make sure you use "await"..

Comment: You know that compiler warning you get with the `async` method? Read it. It will tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 36):

Adding `async`, by itself, does nothing other than allow the method body to use the `await` keyword.  A properly implemented async method won't block the UI thread, but an improperly implemented one most certainly can.

What you probably wanted to do was this:

```
async private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    MessageBox.Show("All done!");
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`async` by itself will not enable asynchronous (non-blocking) method invocation.
You should use `await` inside the `async` function.

You should read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) to have a better understanding of this capability.

Answer (score 1):

1) The Async key work makes the method asynchrounous with no blocking, by time slicing. Async must exist with await, that tell to wait for the completion of the task, but all the
stuff before will be executed.

```
async private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var task = Task.Delay(1000);

    /*Do stuff*/

    await task;
}
```

2) Just make a thread sleep only, any code above will not execute, only after the thread sleep finish the task.

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    /*Do stuff*/
}
```

Theres a good read at msdn [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)!

Comment: Your task is doing a blocking wait there, which is needlessly consuming a thread pool's time.  By using `Task.Delay` you can make the entire thing properly asynchronous, rather than using async over sync.