# Why GetIsNetworkAvailable() method always returning value as true with vpn client reconnecting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, visual-studio-2010, vpn

I am working on a offline mode for a project in `C#`.

A user connected to his enterprise network via `vpn` client at home. If internet connectivity has gone and immediately the next one minute, the particular `vpn` client try to reconnect. In this situation the below method `GetIsNetworkAvailable()` gives the internet connectivity state as `True`. But logically i am not connected to Internet.

Is there any way get the correct internet connectivity state when my vpn client try to reconnect.

```
bool isConnected = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

Comment: I think your definition of "correct internet connectivity state" differs from the one Microsoft uses.

Comment: the below method is taking 30 to 45 seconds to give the result if i am not connected to internet and my vpn client try to do reconnecting..

 IPHostEntry dummy = Dns.GetHostEntry("www.google.com"); 

Please note i have no intention to waste any one of time. I have real problem and asking real question. Not like MSDN Forum,  i can't ask my own question. Everyone top of my question and try to destroy my question :(

Comment: At least it's still under a minute though...

Comment: Since i am calling this method more frequently in my application to know user offline state, my application is being unresponsive for 1 minute when user's vpn client try to reconnect when internet is not there.. This is my problem.

Comment: Then use an [asynchronous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406591/async-modifier-in-c-sharp) method instead.

Comment: i tried async as well and there is no big difference.

Comment: Create a new property, then update the property from a separate thread.

Comment: You could try using [Dns.GetHostEntryAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostentryasync.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Sam. But Dns.GetHostEntryAsync will only work for .Net Framework 4.5. But my code is on .net framework 4.

Comment: Your welcome. Can't you move up to 4.5? Other than that, i can't think of anything else.

Comment: If i have google's IP in my DNS cache, it won't send a DNS request, so it could return true even when i am not connected