# Async Method Seemingly Not Running Asynchronously C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

The following seemingly simple scenario is causing me problems:

```
    private List<Task> _Tasks = new List<Task>();
    void someMethod() {
      //stuff

      prepareWork();
      Task.WaitAll(_Tasks.ToArray());

      //do more stuff
    }

    private void prepareWork() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
         _Tasks.Add(someWork());
         //_Tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => someWork())); //<---- This does work
      }
    }

    private async Task someWork() {
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
```

I would expect someWork() to be run asynchronously, but it is not the case. It becomes the case when I replace the `_Tasks.Add(someWork());` line with the commented line underneath. It seems to me I am missing something fundamental about the way C#/async and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Async method will run synchronously if there's no await. You can try replacing `Thread.Sleep` with `await Task.Delay`.

Comment: @Leisen Chang, that's really helpful. I have calls with await in my real code, but I think I am not awaiting what actually takes a while.

Comment: Your `async` method doesn't ever actually yield, and so executes synchronously. It won't return until the sleep finishes, so by the time your loop finishes adding tasks, they're all done. This is exactly like the marked duplicate -- the `async` method there also doesn't yield, though in that case it has an infinite loop and so the program makes no progress at all. But either way, same issue: `async` only helps if your method is actually asynchronous.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, thanks! I feel silly at that point, I wish the question could be closed now haha. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but definitely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406591/async-modifier-in-c-sharp

Answer (score -1):

> This is not the answer (and partially incorrect) but leaving as comment by Peter below add a
>   valid and overlooked point.
>
> Will delete if Peter can put in an answer to the question

When you are adding tasks, you have just created the work to be done. But as you noticed it has not yet started.

```
_Tasks.Add(someWork());
```

To run any task you have to call its start method, to run all task in the list you can start them and then wait as you are doing for all to complete.

```
_task.ForEach(t=>t.Start());
```

Comment: I believe this is not the case. Calling prepareWork() blocks for 4 seconds because the calls to someWork() are run sequencially. They do in fact run. My problem is that I don't see why I have add them to the list by running `_Tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => someWork()));` for it to behave the way I want to.

Comment: _"To run any task you have to call its start method"_ -- this is not correct. An `async` method is an implicit representation of a `Task` object, and simply calling the method (as the OP's code does) is sufficient to cause it to run. The issue here is not that a task isn't started, it's that the task is implemented so as to complete synchronously, and so the `async` aspect of it becomes moot.